# XML Tree View : Iam using XMLTree.js as plugin to show my xml in tree view in jQuery, can i edit my leaf node

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, xml-parsing

Iam using XMLTree.js as plugin to display my xml in tree structure. Tree view iam able to see but i want to edit my node value.
Can anyone help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Live XML Editor](http://www.subchild.com/liveXmlEdit/index.php#) instead.